# Delphi : хранение и просмотр doc (docx) файла

Tags: doc, delphi, ole

Есть одна папка, в ней много вордовских файлов (с таблицами, формулами).
Нужно эти файлы открыть с помощью Delphi (7, 2010 или XE2) только для просмотра документа. Как это лучше реализовать?
У меня есть несколько вариантов:

- Через мемористрим загружать в память с папки, тогда файлы будут в файловой системе, что мне не нравится.
- Хранить в БД, например, в MySQL в поле типа OLE. Раньше не пробовал работать, если будут примеры - буду очень признателен. Плюсы: не будем засорять папку, все в одном файлике БД.
- Упаковать вордовские файлы в один .dat файл. Возможно ли так? Просто я так раньше делал с картинками, а документами не пробовал. Здесь тоже, как бы вместо папки получаем один красивый .dat файл, и документы скрыты от чужих глаз.
- Как то знакомый сказал, что док файлы надо преобразовать в .mht и через веб-браузер(компонент) открывать для просмотра.

Скажите какой способ выбрать для хранения и открытия для просмотра?

Answer (score 1):

Ничего не понял. Файловая система уже представляет собой по сути базу данных с доступом по ключу - имени файла. И ваять велосипед смысла не имеет. Если требуется, чтобы файлы были доступны только для чтения, то что мешает поставить необходимые атрибуты ФС и права доступа? Это первое. Во-вторых, если Вы хотите сделать какой-либо проект, где эти doc-файлы не будут доступны пользователю или эффективность хранения файлов в ФС вызывает сомнения, то doc-файлы можно упаковать. Можно просто сделать zip или rar-архив под паролем и с измененным расширением, а можно просто сохранить бинарные данные в SQL базу данных. Все зависит от кол-ва файлов, их размера, требуемой эффективности работы и доп. критериев...